# strange things on mybatis :Mapped Statements collection does not contain value for

Tags: junit, mybatis

There is a very strange problem happened when i tested the code on mybatis + spring with junit4.

It is ok to run in normal way - jetty environment?

But when it run on junit, errors appear.

BaseTest.java

```
package com.test.spring.action;

import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
import org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionConfiguration;

@ContextConfiguration(
        {"classpath:application-context.xml"
})
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@TransactionConfiguration(transactionManager="transactionManager",defaultRollback=true)
public class BaseTest extends AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests{

}
```

UserAction.java

```
package com.test.spring.action;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import com.test.spring.service.UserService;
@Component
public class UserAction extends BaseTest{

    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(BaseTest.class);
    @Autowired
    UserService userService;

    @Test
    public void testInsertAccount() {
        userService.getAll();

    }
}
```

the xml configrations below:

application-context.xml

```
....
<bean id="sqlSessionFactory" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean">  
       <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
       <property name="typeAliasesPackage" value="com.test.spring.entity"/>
        <!-- mapper和resultmap配置路径 -->
        <property name="mapperLocations">
            <list>
                <value>classpath:com/test/spring/mapper/*-mapper.xml</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean> 
 .....
```

user-mapper.xml

```
<mapper namespace="com.test.spring.mapper.UserMapper">

    <select id="getAll" resultType="user">
        <![CDATA[
            select * from user
        ]]>
    </select>  ...others selects
```

Could anyone help me figure out what's wrong with it?

I can provide more detail if you want.

Thanks.

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: Mapped Statements collection does not contain value for xxClass.methodName

Comment: This error means that there is syntax error in xml mapping.

Comment: Yes,thank you.It can not resolve xml configration which contains Chinese.My god!

Comment: Three names have to match - https://stackoverflow.com/a/60616498/715269